# Better way, of writing a Long "if" statements?

Tags: python, if-statement

Hello this might be a very basic question, but because I am new to programming and python and I really want to learn, am asking.

I am making a program that takes input from the user, of the "Playing Card" Suit he has. And the program only accepts the correct suit.

For example;

> Diamonds, Hearts, Clubs, Spades

if the user enters anything else, such as "Triangles" the program returns "Wrong input".

This is what I have got so far:

```
if suit == "Diamonds":
    return "Accepted"
if suit == "Hearts":
    return "Accepted"
if suit == "Clubs":
    return "Accepted"
if suit == "Spades":
    return "Accepted"
else:
    return "Wrong input"
```

My question was, is there a better way to write this than going through this tedious process of making a whole new "if" statement for each Suit.

Comment: As a side note, you should really be using `elif` here (well, until you swap out for one of the answers).  `if` is going to be less efficient, and also lead to subtle bugs if you ever have conditions that aren't as clearly mutually exclusive as these.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if suit in ("Diamonds","Hearts","Clubs","Spades"):
    return "Accepted"
else:
    return "Wrong input"
```

Just use `in` to check for membership, if `suit` is not in the tuple, your `else` clause will be executed.

[membership operators](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/membership_operators_example.htm)

You can also reverse the logic using `not in`:

```
if suit not in ("Diamonds","Hearts","Clubs","Spades"):
    return "Wrong input"
else:
    return "Accepted"
```

If you want to check for a value also:

```
if suit  in ("Diamonds","Hearts","Clubs","Spades") and value in ("Ace","king","Queen"....):
    return "Accepted"
else:
    return "Wrong input"
```

Using a [set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) `{"Diamonds","Hearts","Clubs","Spades"}` is a more efficient way to check for membership

Comment: And what if there are 2 if statements. One if statement for the Suit and the other for the Value of the card... will the **"else"** statement interfere with the other "if" statement?

Comment: @Ali,  so you want to know the specific suit?

Comment: something like this... the user enters the value of the Card and Suit... so if it is 38 of diamonds... then it should also return wrong

Comment: @Ali, you can use an `and` to check for both

Comment: Learnt something New.. and a very much neater and cleaner way to do this ! Thank you very much for taking out the time and helping me :)

Answer (score 8):

You can use `in` to check if `suit` is in a list, tuple or set of accepted suits:

```
if suit in {"Diamonds", "Hearts", "Clubs", "Spades"}:
    return "Accepted"
else:
    return "Wrong input"
```

You can also use a `tuple` (with `(...)`), `list` (`[...]`) or `frozenset` instead of the `set` (`{...}`).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `in` operator:

```
accepted = ['Diamonds', 'Hearts', 'Clubs', 'Spades']
if suit in accepted:
  return "accepted"
else:
  return "wrong input"
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this suits your needs, but sometime an alternative approach using dictionary might help with long sequences of `if ... elif`:

```
states = {"Diamonds": "accepted",
          "Hearts":   "accepted",
          "Clubs":    "accepted",
          "Spades":   "accepted"}
return states.get(suit,"wrong input")
```

Comment: humm very interesting... This actually could be incorporated into my program in some way.